Can't parse this CRS_WKT
When I try to load EPSG:6871 i get the folowing error code:
Failed to get coordinate reference system for code 6871

Question:
Instead I would like to try this (see below) WKT-CRS (copied from QGIS) in GeoTools, but when I'm trying to use CRS.parseWKT("...") it will not work.
Is it a WKT dialect not supported by Geotools?
Error:
org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException: Type "PROJCRS" is unknow in this context. 
at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ReferencingObjectFactory.createFromWKT(ReferencingObjectFactory.java:1132) 
at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.parseWKT(CRS.java:565)

If I change to "PROJCS" then other error occurs...
WKT:
PROJCRS["World_Mercator",

    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",

        ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",

            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],

            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],

            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],

            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],

            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],

            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],

            MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"],

            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,

                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],

            ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],

        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,

            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],

        ID["EPSG",4326]],

    CONVERSION["World_Mercator",

        METHOD["Mercator (variant B)",

            ID["EPSG",9805]],

        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",0,

            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],

            ID["EPSG",8823]],

        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,

            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],

            ID["EPSG",8802]],

        PARAMETER["False easting",0,

            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],

            ID["EPSG",8806]],

        PARAMETER["False northing",0,

            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],

            ID["EPSG",8807]]],

    CS[Cartesian,2],

        AXIS["(E)",east,

            ORDER[1],

            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],

        AXIS["(N)",north,

            ORDER[2],

            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],

    USAGE[

        SCOPE["Not known."],

        AREA["World."],

        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],

    ID["ESRI",54004]]

Proj4
+proj=merc +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
Extension:
-180.00, -90.00, 180.00, 90.00

What does 'does not work' mean? Does it raise an error, not raise an error but the data is  not in the right location, is the data geolocated on Mars, does your computer burst into flames... something more descriptive than 'does not work' would be appreciated.

Your WKT defines an ESRI projection ESRI:54004. Current Proj shows this projinfo epsg:6871 Warning: object is deprecated Alternative non-deprecated CRS:  EPSG:6893 +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +geoidgrids=us_nga_egm08_25.tif +geoid_crs=WGS84 +vunits=m +type=crs.

Are you sure that WKT describes EPSG:6871? Your parameters don't match the CRS listed on epsg.io https://epsg.io/6871, yours has a standard parallel and origin, epsg.io has a central meridian (Greenwich) and scale factor.

@MichaelStimson Error:org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException: Type "PROJCRS" is unknow in this context.
at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ReferencingObjectFactory.createFromWKT(ReferencingObjectFactory.java:1132)
at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.parseWKT(CRS.java:565)

@MichaelStimson, first I tried to load 6871, it did not work, then I tried to use this ESRI projection 54004 instead, but the parsing did not work.

It should be PROJCS not PROJCRS ref https://docs.ogc.org/is/18-010r7/18-010r7.html item B.8. I suggest you copy the OGC WKT from epsg.io; please note EPSG:6871 is depreciated https://epsg.io/?q=World%20kind%3ACOMPOUNDCRS%20%20deprecated%3A1 please edit your question to include the new information.

I tried the GeoServer SRS List demo (GS 2.24.3, GeoTools 30.3), and both the deprecated EPSG:6871 and the valid EPSG:6893 were found. What GeoTools version do you use? There is a mixture of org.opengis.referencing and org.geotools.referencing here: org.Error:org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException: Type "PROJCRS" is unknow in this context. at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ReferencingObjectFactory.createFromWKT. Could there be something wrong with your GeoTools build? I think that the opengis stuff was removed some time ago.

org.opengis.* should not exist in any recent (i.e. current) release of GeoTools

The official EPSG (epsg.org) page for epsg:6871 (https://epsg.org/crs_6871/WGS-84-Pseudo-Mercator-EGM2008-geoid-height.html ) tells you that it is deprecated, but also what replaces it epsg:6893 (https://epsg.org/crs_6893/WGS-84-World-Mercator-EGM2008-height.html)
